# Remove price filter from category view Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price-slider

How can I disable the price filter to show on category view?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just go  `store > Attributes > Product` from backend and search `price` attribute from among list and open `price` attribute and set `Use in Search Results Layered Navigation` to `NO` and save.

[image]

after saving this attribute don't forgot to do `reindex` and clear your website `cache`

**EDIT**

Please check below Image

[image]

Comment: In Magento 2 there is no attribute under **Stores**

Comment: @Omer You have to click on Stores from left sidebar admin, Now go to Attribtes -> Product link.

Comment: Please see my edit @Omer